# How to search a string in a file and print the line shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file where there is a lot of books with index number.

I want to search the books with index number.

The file format is kind of like this:

> "The Declaration of Independence of the United States of America,
>   1
>
> by Thomas Jefferson"
>
> ......................
>
> Alice's Adventures in Wonderland, by Lewis Carroll
>   11

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the content your are searching for:"  
read content
echo -e "\nResult Shwoing For: $content\n"
grep $content GUTINDEX.ALL
```

If user search for 1.This code is printing 1, 11 every line that has one in them. I want to only print the line which contains 1:

> "The Declaration of Independence of the United States of America,  1

Answer (score 0):

simple use the `-w` flag, read more at `grep --help`

```
grep -w ${line_number} ${file_name}
```

for `grep -w 1 books`

> The Declaration of Independence of the United States of America 1
>
> Bobs's 1 in Wonderland, by Lewis Carroll 11

it may catch book names that contains number,
so better use regex `[${digit}]$` for example `[1]$` for matching
index at end of line.

```
grep -w [${line_number}]$ ${file_name}
```

for `grep -w 1$ books`

> The Declaration of Independence of the United States of America, 1

Answer (score 0):

you need to use regex. Change grep to egrep.

file:

```
1
11
111
```

if you want to search only 1 then you can use

cat file | egrep "^1$"       # it means start and end with 1.`

then you need extend scrip. For example
 **file.txt**

```
abc,1
abd,111
abf,11111
```

## #

```
cat file.txt | while read line ; do
 res=$(echo ${line} | awk -v FS=',' '{print $2}' | grep "^1$")
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo $line
 fi
done
```